# Error Occurs with QUIC_TLS_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN When Attempting WebTransport Connection

Tags: chromium, tls1.3, quic, http3, rudp

I'm trying to use Google Chrome's WebTransport connection by following the example provided in https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/webtransport/README.md. I've generated the OpenSSL certificate using the method in webtransport_server.py and applied the generated certificate to Chromium options. However, when attempting to establish a connection at https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/webtransport/client.html, I encounter the net::ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR.QUIC_TLS_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN error. This error appears as "TLS handshake failure (ENCRYPTION_HANDSHAKE) 46: certificate unknown".

I've already registered certificate.pem in Chromium settings and confirmed that the QUIC server is running. Despite these efforts, the problem persists.

Could you please advise on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3weN.png)